# Create table dynamically foreach tag named "table" on birt

Tags: xml, eclipse, dynamic, dataset, birt

I'm trying to create tables dynamically on a report using Eclipse Birt, for each tag named **table** that I have on my XML.

Here's my XML for testing:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
    <table>
        <name>
            <column number="1">First Column</column>
            <column number="2">Second Column</column>
        </name>
        <line>
            <column number="1">1</column>
            <column number="2">2</column>
        </line>
        <line>
            <column number="1">3</column>
            <column number="2">4</column>
        </line>
    </table>
    <table>
        <name>
            <column number="1">A Column</column>
            <column number="2">Another Column</column>
        </name>
        <line>
            <column number="1">A</column>
            <column number="2">B</column>
        </line>
        <line>
            <column number="1">C</column>
            <column number="2">D</column>
        </line>
    </table>
</root>
```

So, what I want here is to create 2 tables like this:

```
----------------------------------
| First Column  |  Second Column |
|       1       |       2        |
|       3       |       4        |
----------------------------------

----------------------------------
|   A Column    | Another Column |
|       A       |       B        |
|       C       |       D        |
----------------------------------
```

And everytime I add a new **table** tag to the XML like the previous ones, I should get another table on my report automatically.

I found [this link](http://digiassn.blogspot.pt/2007/11/birt-dynamic-adding-tables-and-columns.html) that helped me to create tables from code. But now I can't figure out how can I count each table tag from the XML in order to make a for loop to create the tables. I already have a DataSource setup but I don't know what else I need to reach those tags on code.

I'm new to BIRT so can someone tell me if what I'm trying to do is possible and if it is, how can I do that tag part?